# Uncaught ReferenceError: reg is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to build a login and registration form using jquery, ajax and php. But im getting this error when im pressing the button for registration.

```
<!-- Formular for signing up -->
 <form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Username </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newusername"> 
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newpassword"> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Your club </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newclub"> 
    </div>   

    <button type="button" onClick='reg' class="btn btn-success">Sign up!</button>

</form>
```

**And here is my script code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Function for registrate of new users
    function reg(newusername, newpassword, newclub) {
        $.post('class/callingClass.php', {
            newusername: 'newusername',
            newpassword: 'newpassword',
            newclub: 'newclub'
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Don’t put the `reg` function in the `$(document).ready` function. Or attatch the event with a more standard way like `$(".btn-success").click(reg);` or something similar.

Comment: Define `reg()` *outside* of the `document.ready` handler so it's in scope of the `onclick` attribute. **Better yet** - use Javascript to attach your events. This is better because it removes the ugly `onclick` attribute, it's a better separation of concerns, and you will have no scoping issues.

Answer (score 3):

Functions called from `onXYZ` attribute event handlers must be globals (it's one of the several reasons not to use them). Your `reg` function isn't a global, it's nicely contained within your `ready` callback (which is a Good Thing™, the global namespace is already really crowded and prone to conflicts).

Separately, `onClick='reg'` wouldn't work, it would have to be `onClick='reg()'`.

Instead, hook `reg` up dynamically via [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
<button type="button" id="btn-reg" class="btn btn-success">Sign up!</button>
<!-- Removed onClick, added id -->
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-reg").on("click", reg);      // <== Added

    // Function for registrate of new users
    function reg(newusername, newpassword, newclub) {
        $.post('class/callingClass.php', {
            newusername: 'newusername',
            newpassword: 'newpassword',
            newclub: 'newclub'
        });
    };
});
```

I've used an `id` above, but it doesn't have to be an `id`, that's just one way to look up the element. Any CSS selector that would find it would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onClick='reg()'`. You need to do the function call here, which is the proper syntax.

Update : You also need to move your function outside of the `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: While this is the correct syntax, the `reg()` function is not defined in the correct scope, so this alone still won't work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wont the function work after the document is ready?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan: See my answer. It would have to be a global. The OP's isn't a global.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it. I wasn't really thinking.  :)

Comment: I would recommend *against* recommending creating *more* globals.